# How to access a class instance variable from another class without creating a new instance of that class

Tags: ruby

I have a class `Board` that creates a hash:

```
class Board
  attr_accessor :board

  def initialize
    @board = {}
  end

  def generate_board
    i = 0
    until i == 8
      @board[i] = [" . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . "," . "]
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
```

and i'm trying to access it from a different class:

```
class Pawn
  def legal_moves
    possible_moves = []
    if @board[@position[0] + 1][@position[1] + 1].is_a? Piece
      possible_moves << [[@position[0] + 1, @position[1] + 1]]
    end
    if @board[@position[0] + 1][@position[1] - 1].is_a? Piece
      possible_moves << [[@position[0] + 1, @position[1] - 1]]
    end
    @legal_moves = possible_moves
  end
end
```

How can I access this saved board state without creating a new board object? I can't create a new board object because the state of the board will need to be persistent. I already created an original instance in a different class that plays the game.

Comment: Ruby is not Python. You need to close the class with `end`.

Comment: "How can I access this saved board state without creating a new board object?" Which instance of the board is the state saved in? Unless you can make that clear, your question does not make sense.

Comment: In the Play class i run ` a = Board.new` and then all the board methods, but I can't find a way to use this "a" instance of Board in my other classes

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71790/design-a-chess-game-using-object-oriented-principles

Comment: Ruby is not Python. You need to close the class with `end`. And changing the indentation does not make any difference.

Comment: I fixed the end, it got cut off when i pasted in my question

Comment: If I  get the point, you don't need. Just pass the `Board` instance to the `Pawn` method (`def legal_moves(board)`). But it is unclear where `@position` came from. Maybe you can update the question telling what you want to accomplish, somebody could show a different approach. Check this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/communication-between-two-classes-in-ruby

Comment: a refactor suggestion: since your `@board` hash has only keys from 0 to 8 I would initialize it as an array like this `@board = [[" . "] * 8] * 8`

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Can you clarify which class instance variable you are talking about? I don't see any class instance variables in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the board to the new pawn instance.

```
class Pawn
  attr_reader :board, :location_x, :location_y

  def initialize(board)
    @board = board
    @location_x = nil
    @location_y = nil
  end

  def move(x, y)
    if board.get(x, y).nil?
      board.set(location_x, location_y, nil)
      self.location_x = x
      self.location_y = y
      board.set(x, y, self)
    else
      false
    end
  end
end

> board = Board.new
> pawn = Pawn.new(board)
> pawn.move(0,0)
> board.get(0,0) == pawn
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get additional experience with object-oriented programming, you can use [Singleton pattern](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html):

```
require 'singleton'

class Board
  include Singleton

  attr_accessor :board

  def generate_board
    @board = {}
    i = 0
    until i == 8
      @board[i] = [" . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . "," . "]
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
```

In this case, to generate **board** you should call: `Board.instance.generate_board`

And when you need access to **board** from other class, you can add one line to init:

```
class Pawn
  def initialize
    @board = Board.instance.board
  end
end
```

Now you can use `@board` inside `Pawn` object just as you do it in your example:

`@board[@position[0] + 1][@position[1] + 1]`

Good luck!